# drupal_add_js() includes JS with wrong weigth

Tags: 7, javascript

A module I am using on my site uses the `drupal_add_js()` function to include some JavaScript. Although the function is used correctly the JavaScript file is included before the jQuery script which causes an error.

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'rate') . '/rate.js', array('scope' => 'footer', 'group' => JS_THEME));
```

Even if I add the weight option `('weight' => 500)` it keeps be added before the jQuery script.

What am I supposed to do?

I am using newest Drupal 7, Rate API, and Rate widget.

Comment: Try the same but skip the scope => footer part.

Comment: That work's, but why? Should I report that as a bug for the module? But now there is another strange thing happening: The JavaScript is added at the right position but it depends on a value passed from PHP with:`  drupal_add_js(array(
    'rate' => array(
      'basePath' => url('rate/vote/js'),
      'destination' => $dest['destination'],
    )
  ), array('type' => 'setting'));`
This does not work either although it looks right to me.

Comment: Give some more details about your installation - where is $scripts variable located in your html.tpl.php template?

Comment: Both, the drupal_add_js() that adds the file an the drupal_add_js() that adds a setting variable are located in the file rate.module of the rate module. I can't find anything wrong in the implementation, but it does not work, as described above. Thank you for your attention!